# Store attributes by SQL in Arraylist and show on textboxes

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, odbc

I'm making a system where I want to take a SQL data and store in an arraylist.
Example: In the database there are the attributes (name, address, gender ...), these attributes will be stored in an arraylist and then a function will read this arraylist and print the data in the textbox (disabled).

I'm using VS C# 2010, MySQL and ODBC.

An idea: http://snag.gy/HPrny.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you skip the arraylist and simply bind the textboxes to your query results?

Comment: I do not know how to do, how would you explain? If it's the syntax ...

Comment: A google search on "c# bind form field to data" will get you started.

Comment: Remember, there are several attributes of a single ID. Not a single attribute with multiple ID.

Comment: you can do this multiple ways.. you can create a class and stored data that way.. or arraylist as you mentioned.. or simply bind the textboxes to query.. not sure what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try to get it using DataSet:

```
public DataTable GetDBDataTable(MySqlConnection dbconnection, string table, string columns = "*", string clause = "")
{
    MySqlCommand mysqlcmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT " + columns + " FROM " + table + " " + clause +";", dbconnection);
    MySqlDataAdapter mysqlad = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlcmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    mysqlad.Fill(ds);
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    return dt;
}
```

DataTable class on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/FR-FR/library/system.data.datatable.aspx

You can easily operate data in this way :)

If you want to show each entry in a MessageBox:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   int i = 0;
   foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(dt.row.ItemArray[i].ToString();
      i++;
   }
 }
```